# RViz keep saying "No transform from [front_left] to [base_link]"

Tags: ros, joint, rviz, urdf, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

﻿I have a package named sp1s, I added a URDF, as simple as below:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot name="sp1s">
  <link name="base_link">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.27 .15 .003"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="white">
         <color rgba="1 1 1 .5"/>
    </material>
    </visual>
  </link>
  
  <link name="front_left">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
       <cylinder length=".025" radius="0.034"></cylinder>
      </geometry>
      <material name="yellow">
          <color rgba="1 1 0 1"/>
      </material>  
    </visual>
  </link>
  
  <joint name="base_to_front_left" type="continuous">
    <origin rpy="1.57075  0  0" xyz="0.06  0.064  -0.011"/>
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="front_left"/>    
    <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
  </joint>
  
</robot>
```

Here is the launch file I edited:

```
<launch>
    <arg name="model" />
    <arg name="gui" default="False" />
    <param name="robot_description" textfile="$(arg model)" />
    <param name="use_gui" value="$(arg gui)"/>
    <node name="joint_state_publisher" pkg="joint_state_publisher" type="joint_state_publisher" />
    <node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="state_publisher" />
    <node name="rviz" pkg="rviz" type="rviz"  args="-d  $(find sp1s)/urdf.rviz" required="true"/>
</launch>
```

When I launch it by "roslaunch sp1s display.launch model:=urdf/sp1s.urdf",  the Rviz keep saying "No transform from [front_left] to [base_link]".
I double checked my urdf content, I believe it caused by using joint type "continuous".

**I strongly believe its a bug. When I follow the urdf_tutorial by 'roslaunch urdf_tutorial display.launch model:=urdf/06-flexible.urdf gui:=True', it was showing fine. But I changed the 06-flexible.urdf simply by add one space at the last empty line, launch it again it would say same thing on RViz**

Why its happening, how to work around it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201372/rviz-keep-saying-%22no-transform-from-%5Bfront_left%5D-to-%5Bbase_link%5D%22/) by [Dragon Qu](https://answers.ros.org/users/21428/dragon-qu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2015-01-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I got it! It took me a whole day to figure out why.
joint_state_publisher failed to parse the urdf xml file. It dumped error message:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec
> can't encode character

I used XML copy editor to compile the file. It was wrong. I should use Text Editor to do it. joint_state_publisher doesn't support Unicode xml file.  But check_urdf is fine with that.

---

Originally posted by [Dragon Qu](https://answers.ros.org/users/21428/dragon-qu/) with karma: 73 on 2015-01-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2015-01-21**:
Glad you could figure it out. In the future, when something breaks like this, add the output="screen" attribute to nodes that might be giving you trouble so that you can see these error messages easier.